# get header and file get coontient to curl

Tags: curl, file-get-contents, get-headers

Hi I'd like to transform this small code into curl. Is this possible?

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/test.php';
$file_headers = @get_headers($url);
if ( strpos($file_headers[0], "200") )
{
    $check = @file_get_contents($url);
    if (stristr($check,"/Style.js"))
        echo "<font color='green'>FOUND</font>";
    else
        echo "<font color='red'>NOT FOUND</font>";
}
?>
```

I am trying to check the status of a site and after that to find out whether 
a link to the file "/Style.js" (just this substring) is present in the file test.php or not.

Comment: Please post in English. I've suggested a semi-robot translation along with improved formatting of the code, but it's not clear what do you mean by "the file Style.js is in the file test.php or not" (initially "si le fichier Style.js dans le fichier test.php ou non ctt")

Comment: dans le fichier test.php il y'a cette balise  <SCRIPT SRC='http://www.example.com/Style.js'></SCRIPT> je veut chercher si mot  /Style.js dans le fichier ou non